# Geb changing an attribute value

Tags: selenium, spock, geb

I want to know what is the correct way to change any attribute value of an element in geb (selenium).

For example, I have this element:

```
static content = {
    radioSelect(wait: true) { $('input[name=rr]')}
}
```

Now I want to set any attribute. I did not found a good method, I use this workaround:

```
(driver as JavascriptExecutor).executeScript( "document.getElementsByName('rr')[0].setAttribute('checked', true)" )
```

Is there another way? Like radioSelect.setAttribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [jQuery integration](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#jquery-integration) offered by Geb:

```
radioSelect.jquery.attr("checked", true)
```

This is the equivalent of

```
js.exec 'jQuery("input[name=rr]").attr("checked", true)'
```

But be careful:

> The jQuery integration only works when the pages you are working with
>   include jQuery, Geb does not install it in the page for you. The
>   minimum supported version of jQuery is 1.4.